# course.getCourseMaterialSets() is returning empty for Google classroom Course Material

Tags: google-classroom

To Access Course Material In Google Classroom API , I am using the following java library function. It was working last week but not returning any data now ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
                for (Course course : courses) { 
                    System.out.printf("%s \n", course.getName());
                    List<CourseMaterialSet> set = course.getCourseMaterialSets();   
                    if (set != null) {                  
                        for (CourseMaterialSet s : set) {
                            System.out.println(s.toPrettyString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Course material not found");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Did you make any changes to the code? Are you getting any errors associated with this?

Comment: Using another API which is returning the data now.
ListCourseWorkMaterialResponse res = classroom.courses().courseWorkMaterials().list(courseId)     .setCourseWorkMaterialStates(Arrays.asList("PUBLISHED")).execute();